# Rails 5 - How to solve OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: system lib issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, rvm

While trying to create a new rails 5 project I am getting an error like

````
OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: system lib
...
...

### Gemfile.lock

```
<No /home/shruthi/Projects/VSupport/Gemfile.lock found>
```

--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=system+lib&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
````

My rvm list is like

```
    ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
 =* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

When try to resolve it by `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'` then the output is like `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem`

My system's certificate files(name) are `Fortinet_CA_SSL.crt` and `Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.crt`

How to solve this certificate error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `~/.bundle/config` file add `BUNDLE_SSL_CA_CERT: "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/Fortinet/Fortinet_CA_SSLProxy.crt"` and restart your system.

For more details refer https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html